# Entity Framework Search for Enum pulls back all data

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, enums, ef-code-first

I'm executing the following query using entity framework, I'd like to filter my results by the `TakerStatus` which is an `Enum`:

```
var takerCount = this.DbContext.Set<Quiz>().Single(x => x.UrlId == urlId).Takers.Count(x => x.TakerStatus == TakerStatus.Abandoned || x.TakerStatus == TakerStatus.Complete)
```

Here's the `enum`:

```
public enum TakerStatus
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Taker is currently in the process of completing the quiz
    /// </summary>
    InProgess = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// Taker failed to complete the quiz and was marked as abandoned
    /// </summary>
    Abandoned = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Taker successfully completed taking the quiz
    /// </summary>
    Complete = 2
}
```

I realised that this query was running slowly and I wanted to know why, there are a good number of records in there, but I wanted to improve the speed by adding indexes.

But after examining the query that is actually produced by this, I see that it appears to be ignoring the lambda expression...

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`QuizId`, 
`Extent1`.`QuizVersionId`, 
`Extent1`.`UserId`, 
`Extent1`.`TakerName`, 
`Extent1`.`CurrentQuestionNumber`, 
`Extent1`.`CurrentQuestionStartTime`, 
`Extent1`.`CurrentScore`, 
`Extent1`.`Completed`, 
`Extent1`.`IpAddress`, 
`Extent1`.`StartTime`, 
`Extent1`.`FinishTime`, 
`Extent1`.`Abandoned`, 
`Extent1`.`PasswordId`, 
`Extent1`.`PersonalityResultId`, 
`Extent1`.`PercentageResult`, 
`Extent1`.`Status`, 
`Extent1`.`TakerStatus`
FROM `Taker` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`QuizId` = 330
```

It's selecting every taker for the quiz but not even examining the `TakerStatus` column.

What gives?  I wanted to add an index to `TakerStatus` to speed it up

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I gues it needs a pair of braces around the condition. I think its an operator precedence issue.

```
var takerCount = this.DbContext.Set<Quiz>().Single(x => x.UrlId == urlId).Takers.Count(x => (x.TakerStatus == TakerStatus.Abandoned || x.TakerStatus == TakerStatus.Complete))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Single` enumerates your `IQueryable` and triggers the query (the rest of the processing being done in application server memory, on the whole resultset)

I would try :

```
var takerCount = this.DbContext
    .Set<Quiz>()
    .Where(x => x.UrlId == urlId)
    .Select(o=>o.Takers.Count(x => x.TakerStatus == TakerStatus.Abandoned || x.TakerStatus == TakerStatus.Complete))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```